# Multi-valued...cannot be used in a WHERE or HAVING

Tags: ms-access-2010, multivalue

I am not an access professional but use it to help me make my job easier so please excuse my terminology. I will try and explain as best I can.

I need to create a data base that stores the contact and other information about vendors that we use and specifically the services and the countries that they can provide services in but some of these vendors can provide services in multiple countries and can also provide multiple services. So would prefer to be able to use a list with multi-valued entries for ease of use and to prevent having to duplicate the vendor entries for deferment countries and services. (This i can do)

Then i need to create a search form that performs searches on key words, ether the country name, the service or the vendors name. I did this based on the following code i got from the internet:

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()

Dim strsearch As String
Dim strText As String
strText = Me.TxtSearch.Value
strsearch = "SELECT * from Query1 where ((Decipline Like ""*" & strText & "*"") or (Country_OO Like ""*" & strText & "*""))"
Me.RecordSource = strsearch
End Sub
```

(The search part in itself works fine)

> The problem: When I try to use the search with the multi-valued list
>   box I get the following error: Error 3831 the multi-valued 'Country_OO'
>   cannot be used in a WHERE or HAVING clause.

Debug.Print strsearch SELECT * from Query1 where ((Decipline Like "a") or (Country_OO Like "a"))

I know most of you on here are not fans of the *Multi-valued list* but in this case it would work great. Is there a way around this or and alternative that you can suggest? Maybe a way that i can select the from a list then it adds the txt only to the master file?

Comment: Multivalued? Do you mean a textbox with many entries separated by commas? Or a listbox where multiple rows can be selected? What is strText value that is generating sql error? What does strsearch look like after it is created? Use debug.print to show in immediate window. Then copy/paste into your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768152/appending-multi-value-lists?rq=1  good suggestion for similar problem

Comment: Hi, Multivalued -  Listbox where multiple rows can be selected. So it is a listbox that contains a list of all the countries in Africa.The debug highlights this section > Me.RecordSource = strsearch

Comment: REPEAT... Use `Debug.Print strsearch` Open Immediate Window and then copy/paste into question

Comment: Debug.Print strsearch
SELECT * from Query1 where ((Decipline Like "*a*") or (Country_OO Like "*a*"))

Comment: If i use a normal single-valued list or a normal textbox then the search function works fine.

Comment: "Country_OO" doesn't match with your Error Message that says "Country". What SQL is in Query1?  - your code is using 'strText = Me.TxtSearch.Value' not a list box

Comment: Yes, when i asked the question the name of the field was "Country" but i have been working on it, trying to work around it and the same field is now "Country_OO" .Query1 is only a select query to select 3 fields from the master table? I googled how to make a search box. That is the code that I found, like said i used it and it works but as soon as i changes the field in the master table to a lookup list that can select multiple values then I get the error massage as reported above. I am not a professional and i am pretty much self taught. That's why I have asked for help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your (good!) question title to Google leads directly [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-6f64f92d-659f-411c-9503-b6624e1e323a#bm4_6), which suggests that

```
WHERE Country_OO.Value Like "*a*"
```

should work.

But it would really be better to not use multi-valued fields. Ever.

Comment: This seams to have been the answer to my problem. Thank you.